How do I deal with redis server disconnection in nest.js using cache manager?
So I setup cache manager in nest.js using redis like follwing code.
CacheModule.registerAsync<RedisClientOptions>({
      imports: [ConfigModule],
      inject: [ConfigService, WINSTON_MODULE_PROVIDER],
      useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService, logger: Logger) => {
        const store = await redisStore({
          socket: {
            host: configService.get<string>('REDIS_HOST'),
            port: parseInt(configService.get<string>('REDIS_PORT')!),
            reconnectStrategy: (times) => {
              logger.error(`Attempting to reconnect to redis: ${times} times`);
              if (times > 5) {
                return false;
              }
              return Math.min(times * 50, 2000);
            },
          },
          username: configService.get<string>('REDIS_USERNAME'),
          password: configService.get<string>('REDIS_PASSWORD'),
        });

        return {
          store: {
            create: () => store as unknown as CacheStore,
          },
        };
      },
      isGlobal: true,
    })

But the problem is when the redis server gets terminated for some reason, the nest.js server shuts down too.
The retry logic doesn't really work. I want my nest.js server to retry the socket connection when redis server shuts down.
No matter how long I googled about this, I could not find the solution. Could you guys help me?

Actually I solved this problem using some packages: ioredis, @tirke/node-cache-manager-ioredis.
I used the 2nd package just because of the typing. The documentation is not that kind so, I needed some guide from auto completion.
The tricky part is to integrate redis into CacheModule of Nest.js. Guide in Official Documentation uses cache-manager-redis-store which is based on redis package. However, redis package doesn't really offer any option for retry.
There is a retry option in socket key of RedisClientOption type but it didn't work.
Anyway I wrote this code snippet with the packages I mentioned above I used and it totally worked and it retried when either the connection doesn't exist from the beginning or gets terminated in the middle of the runtime of the applicaiton.
I hope this helps if there is any guy who faces this difficulty.
import Redis from 'ioredis';
import { ioRedisStore } from '@tirke/node-cache-manager-ioredis';

// ... code 
CacheModule.registerAsync({
      imports: [ConfigModule],
      inject: [ConfigService],
      useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => {
        const redisClient = new Redis({
          host: configService.get<string>('REDIS_HOST'),
          port: parseInt(configService.get<string>('REDIS_PORT')!, 10),
          username: configService.get<string>('REDIS_USERNAME'),
          password: configService.get<string>('REDIS_PASSWORD'),
          retryStrategy: (times) => {
            if (times > 600) {
              return null; // Do not retry further
            }
            return 1000;
          },
        });

        return {
          store: ioRedisStore({
            redisInstance: redisClient,
          }),
        };
      },
      isGlobal: true,
    })
// ... code

